# Haskell: convert from a structure of Maybes to a Hashmap

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a pattern cropping up often. I have a structure like this one:

```
data Foo = Foo
  { foo  :: Maybe Text
  , bar  :: Maybe Text
  , buz  :: Maybe Text
  }
```

I want to convert it to a map with labels-values, discarding Nothing values:

```
myMap :: [(Text, Text)]
```

for example: `myMap = [("foo", "val1"), ("bar", "val2")]`

What is the most elegant way to do that?
I have tried with patterns such as `if isJust ... then fromJust ... else Nothing` and then use `catMaybes` but it's not very elegant IMO.

In practice my structure is more heterogeneous:

```
data Foo = Foo
  { foo  :: Maybe Text
  , bar  :: Maybe Bool
  , buz  :: Maybe Int
  }
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
myMap :: [(Text, Value)]
```

Is there a Lens way for this?

Comment: A type signature such as `myMap :: [(Text, Value)]` seems to imply that all fields have the same type. Lists have to be homogeneous.

Comment: @jpmarinier sorry, I forgot to mention that It's Value from Aeson: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.4.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value

Comment: @cdupont: you can let Haskell derive an instance for `ToJson` automatically and then use that to generate key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can let Haskell automatically derive the instance of `ToJson`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Text(Text)
import Data.Aeson(ToJSON)

import GHC.Generics(Generic)

data Foo = Foo
  { foo  :: Maybe Text
  , bar  :: Maybe Bool
  , buz  :: Maybe Int
  } deriving Generic

instance ToJSON Foo
```

You can then filter out the items where the value is `Null`:

```
import Data.Aeson(Value(Null, Object), toJSON)
import Data.HashMap.Strict(toList)

kvs :: Foo -> [(Text, Value)]
kvs foo
    | Object obs <- toJSON foo = filter ((Null /=) . snd) (toList obs)
    | otherwise = []
```

For example:

```
Prelude> kvs (Foo Nothing (Just True) (Just 14))
[("buz",Number 14.0),("bar",Bool True)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not lens, but at least it is simple with list comprehensions:

```
quux :: Foo -> [(String, Text)]
quux v = [ (a,b) | (a, Just b) <- zip ["foo", "bar", "buz"] 
                                 $ map ($ v) [foo, bar, buz]]
```

or your second request,

```
quux2 :: Foo -> [(String, Value)]
quux2 v = [ (a,b) | (a, Just b) <- zip ["foo", "bar", "buz"] 
                    $ map ($ v) 
                       [(TextValue <$>) . foo, 
                          (BoolValue <$>) . bar, (IntValue <$>) . buz]]
```

supposing

```
TextValue :: Text -> Value
BoolValue :: Bool -> Value
IntValue :: Int -> Value
```

Yeah, this quickly becomes brittle and unwieldy. But the first variant is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I love list comprehension. Although I always forget to use them...